# Routing Error for Two-Layer Deep Scoped Controller (uninitialized constant)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

So I've been looking to namespace a few of folders in the project.

When I namespace 1-Layer deep, I have no issues, but as soon as I scope the route down to another folder deeper (and corresponding controller folders/names), I am getting this error:

`Routing Error uninitialized constant Individuals`

What I mean by folder depth, is taking `tyres_controller.rb`, and this layer of depth in the project:

- **1-Layer**
  `app/controllers/<1st_level_deep>/tyres_controller.rb`
- **2-Layers**
  `app/controllers/<1st_level_deep>/<2nd_level_deep>/tyres_controller.rb`

Here's the two scenarios:

**1-Layer Deep Namespaced Controller**

**`app/controllers/tyre_checks/tyre_checks_controller.rb`**

```
module TyreChecks
  class TyreChecksController < ApplicationController
   ...
  end
end
```

**`routes.rb`**

```
scope module: 'tyre_checks' do
  resources :tyre_checks, only: [:new, :create] do
  end
end

...

match '/tyre-checks', to: 'tyre_checks/tyre_checks#new', via: :get, as: :start_tyre_check
```

**2-Layer Deep Namespaced Controller**

**`app/controllers/tyre_checks/individuals/tyre_checks_controller.rb`**

```
module TyreChecks
  module Individuals
    class TyreChecksController < ApplicationController
     ...
    end
  end
end
```

**`routes.rb`**

```
scope module: 'tyre_checks' do
  scope module: 'individuals' do
    resources :tyre_checks, only: [:new, :create] do
    end
  end
end

...

match '/individuals/tyre-check', to: 'individuals/tyre_checks/tyre_checks#new', via: :get, as: :start_tyre_check
```

**IF YOU ASKED ME TO GUESS**

- I think it's something to do with this part and the way Rails interprets the extra `/` in the request at the end of `individuals`:

`to: 'individuals/tyre_checks/tyre_checks#new', via: :get, as: :start_tyre_check`

Comment: can you try defining your controller as `class TyreChecks::Individuals::TyreChecksController < ApplicationController` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realised what I did, an easy mistake to make when defining the route, misled myself based on the initial matched URL (`match '/individuals/tyre-check'`).

Essentially, if you look at the controller structure, it is namespaced as such:

```
module TyreChecks
  module Individuals
    class TyreChecksController < ApplicationController
     ...
    end
  end
end
```

Which when translated to `controller#action` format is:

`tyre_checks/individuals/tyre_checks#action`

but what I did was to put:

`individuals/tyre_checks/tyre_checks#action`

I flipped them around the wrong way. It was the first part I wrote that misled me here:

`match '/individuals/tyre-check'`

All sorted now ;)